# Determining a Function Call to Execute Later

Tags: c#

So I am trying to program a battle system, very much like Pokémon, where the user can select a move, an enemy move is generated and then both are carried out in an order determined by their speed stats.
The types of move I want the player to perform can vary, such as an attack defined by a function with 3 parameters or to switch with another player, defined by a function with just 2 parameters. So what I need to do is determine a function call with different functions and parameters that would program some action and then store it somehow so I can call it later on when it's their turn.
I am struggling to figure out how to achieve this. The only method I could think of involves writing the function call as a string and then executing it later, however this would not be elegant, especially since C# has no handy way of executing strings.
If anyone has any suggestions on how I could achieve this it'd be greatly appreciated :)

EDIT: Here's my code

```
manager.attack (10, currentPlayer, enemy);
checkIfPlayerWon ();
manager.attack (10, enemy, currentPlayer);
checkIfPlayerLost ();
```

So it is the manager.attack part where I'd like to replace with whatever move is to be carried out. So it could be manager.attack() or it could be manager.switchPlayers() with 2 parameters instead.

Comment: C# allows you to compile an string as code, so it can be one way, but I think what you need is reflection, program hardcoded the functions and execute them dinamycally through reflection.

Comment: Sounds like you're just looking for a delegate. No need for string parsing or anything like that. It would be easier to help you if you'd provide a concrete example in code though.

Comment: So I looked at delegates but I thought they had to have a set number of parameters. So code wise I have this:
`manager.attack (10, currentPlayer, enemy);
checkIfPlayerWon ();
manager.attack (10, enemy, currentPlayer);
checkIfPlayerLost ();`
What I want is to replay the attack function with whatever the move is. So it could be manager.attack or manager.switchPlayers which would just take two parameters.

Comment: You can save a keyvaluepair of the delegate and an array of objects that would be send as parameter to the method in question

Answer (score 0):

I think what Jon Skeet was suggesting is to create a delegate with a specific number of parameters (even 0) that *wraps* the action. Then you can pass it around and call it whenever the time is right.

Rough example:

```
private Action GetPlayerAction(manager, player, enemy, actionType, param1, param2, param3)
{
    switch(actionType) {
        case actionType1:
            return () => { manager.attack(param1, player, enemy); checkIfPlayerWon(); }
        case actionType2:
            return () => manager.heal(param2, player);
        // ....
    }
}


// to use
var playerAction = GetPlayerAction(manager, player, enemy, param1, param2);

// do some things ...

playerAction();
```

Comment: Thank you for expanding on this.
So if I understand correctly, I would create a delegate function with the maximum number of parameters needed by the functions it calls, and then return the result of the appropriate function?